# Efficient way to output subset of data frame based on column

Tags: r

With

```
df <- data.frame(week = rep(1:7, each = 2), value = round(rnorm(14), 2))
```

I want to write out `df` into 7 (depending on the `week` column) separate files with each week as a single file. For instance:

```
1.tsv
1   0.49
1   1.04

2.tsv
2   0.40
2   0.97

...

7.tsv
7   -0.03
7   0.52
```

I came up with this:

```
for (wk in unique(df$week)) {
    write.table(df[df$week == wk, ]
          , file = paste(wk, ".tsv", sep = "")
          , sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F)
}
```

but was curious if there is a better way to do the job without using a `for` loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can often use the same construct you're using inside a `for` loop in function and combined with one of the `apply` family:

```
myfun <- function(wk) {
   write.table(df[df$week == wk, ]
          , file = paste(wk, ".tsv", sep = "")
          , sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F, quote = F)
}

lapply(unique(df$week), myfun)
```

However, for clarity, I think the `for` loop option is better.  Also, the speed of the two will be very similar for an operation like this.  The real advantage to the `apply` family is when you need to "grow" a data structure whose size you cannot know before hand.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, Justin. Guess this is just what I want. I'm always confused with the `apply` family and couldn't figure out a good way to use them.

Answer (score 3):

Using `split` and `Map` is one option.

```
df.split <- split(df, df$week)
invisible( # hide Map return value, just a list of NULLs.
    Map(write.table, x=df.split, file=paste(names(df.split), "tsv", sep="."), 
        row.names=F, col.names=F, quote=F)
)
```

Comment: Pretty cool. Thanks! I like it except it requires creating extra object.